# How does Mathematica select principal roots of complex numbers?

Tags: equation-solving, complex, exponent

When I do

```
I^(1/3)
```

I get

```
Out[]:= (-1)^(1/6)
```

which is one of the solutions of $z^3=i$. There are two more solutions which are not given here, which shouldn't be expected. However, the definition of the [principal root of a complex number is ambiguous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322481/principal-nth-root-of-a-complex-number) and therefore I wonder how Mathematica selects the root. What are its criteria?

Comment: It seems to usually be the second solution to `Solve[z^k==I,z]` for whatever positive integer `k`, which is the `z` that has the smallest positive `Arg`, but I can't be sure if that's always the case.

Comment: It's the first non-real root as you traverse ccw from the positive real axis.